# how to reduce the code in tableView cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

hey i'm in the process of learning to code. I created an app that downloads JSON data - covid.
It looks like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t1z5.png)

my code in function (code below) has become terribly large.
how can I reduce this code?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.covidCell, for: indexPath) as! CovidCell
    
    if inSearchMode == true {
        
        cell.countryLabel.text = filterCovidData[indexPath.row].country
        
        cell.regionLabele.text = filterCovidData[indexPath.row].continent
        cell.casesLabel.text = "Case: \(filterCovidData[indexPath.row].cases!)"
        cell.deathLabel.text = "Death: \(filterCovidData[indexPath.row].deaths!)"
        cell.activelabel.text = "Active: \(filterCovidData[indexPath.row].active!)"
        cell.testsLabel.text = "Test: \(filterCovidData[indexPath.row].tests!)"
        cell.todayCasesInfo.text = "\(filterCovidData[indexPath.row].todayCases!)"
        
        let imageUrl = filterCovidData[indexPath.row].countryInfo?.flag
        
        fetchImage(withUrlString: imageUrl!) { (image) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.countryFlag.image = image
            }
        }
        
    } else {
        cell.countryLabel.text = covidData[indexPath.row].country
        cell.regionLabele.text = covidData[indexPath.row].continent
        cell.casesLabel.text = "Case: \(covidData[indexPath.row].cases!)"
        cell.deathLabel.text = "Death: \(covidData[indexPath.row].deaths!)"
        cell.activelabel.text = "Active: \(covidData[indexPath.row].active!)"
        cell.testsLabel.text = "Test: \(covidData[indexPath.row].tests!)"
        cell.todayCasesInfo.text = "\(covidData[indexPath.row].todayCases!)"
        
        let imageUrl = covidData[indexPath.row].countryInfo?.flag
        
        fetchImage(withUrlString: imageUrl!) { (image) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.countryFlag.image = image
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the repetitive code.
You do the same, except the source of the populate, so, let's just retrieve the model according to your needs (inSearchMode), and then let's call the same code.

```
let model = inSearchMode ? filterCovidData[indexPath.row] : covidData[indexPath.row]

cell.countryLabel.text = model.country
    
cell.regionLabele.text = model.continent
cell.casesLabel.text = "Case: \(model.cases!)"
cell.deathLabel.text = "Death: \(model.deaths!)"
cell.activelabel.text = "Active: \(model.active!)"
cell.testsLabel.text = "Test: \(model.tests!)"
cell.todayCasesInfo.text = "\(model.todayCases!)"

let imageUrl = model.countryInfo?.flag

fetchImage(withUrlString: imageUrl!) { (image) in //I'duse a [weak self] here
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.countryFlag.image = image
    }
}
```

That's be the first step.

You can have another logic at start:

```
let arrayToUse = inSearchMode ? filterCovidData : covidData
let model = arrayToUse[indexPath.row]
```

You can also add a code in `CovidCell`

```
func update(model: ModelThatsInsideCovidData) { 
    countryLabel.text = model.country
        
    regionLabele.text = model.continent
    casesLabel.text = "Case: \(model.cases!)"
    deathLabel.text = "Death: \(model.deaths!)"
    activelabel.text = "Active: \(model.active!)"
    testsLabel.text = "Test: \(model.tests!)"
    todayCasesInfo.text = "\(model.todayCases!)"
    
    let imageUrl = model.countryInfo?.flag

    //Here cell doesn't have that method, should it be accessible?, I'll let you decide.
    fetchImage(withUrlString: imageUrl!) { (image) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.countryFlag.image = image
        }
}
```

And then, in cellForRowAt:

```
let model = ...
cell.update(model: model)
return cell
```

Comment: ok I created in CovidCell func:

    func update(model: CovidModel) {
        countryLabel.text = model.country
        ...
    }

and now in table view when I call update func I have error:
 Cannot convert value of type '[CovidModel]' to expected argument type 'CovidModel'

       let model = [CovidModel]()
        cell.update(model: model)
        return cell

Comment: No, it’s let model = inSearchMode ? filterCovidData : covidData